# How to change Dark Souls tutorial and controls to a keyboard

Tags: controllers, dark-souls, keyboard

I recently got Dark Souls for the PC on Steam, and the tutorial and all the control reminders are only for an Xbox 360 controller. Is there any way to change this so I can learn the game for keyboard?

Comment: Can I clarify which game you are asking for? the [tag:dark-souls] tag is for the first game in the series; not for the series itself.

Answer (score 2):

With this mod you can change the promts: http://www.nexusmods.com/darksouls/mods/840/?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer but this is what I did in the same situation:

If you play DS3 just go the [key bindings menu](https://cdn.shazoo.ru/147241_YBCdyNnuIA_hctw9ob.jpg) and check correspondence between controller and keyboard keys.
If you play DS1 you can find DS3 default settings [at the wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Controls), DS1 keybindings is the same expect that you can't bind dash and jump to two different keys.

I really recommend this way because:
0. installing mods takes time.
1. there are not much of controls, so it doesn't take much time to learn them from the settings.
2. default controls are not perfect, so you anyway would want to check out the settings, learn what is what and change some of it (for example I can highly recomend to rebind lock-on from "Q" to somewhere where your right hand will be, I use "O", since I use "JKLI" to move the camera and "HU" to attack).

Comment: What does Dual Shock controllers got to do with his question?

Comment: @YoshiLikes, what are "Dual Shock controllers" and why are you asking me? My answer is about keyboard, and I have never touched a controller, so can answer you nothing.

Comment: You said DS3 and DS1, those are PlayStation controllers.

Comment: @YoshiLikes Those are Dark Souls 3 and Dark Souls 1.

Comment: @Chris Hayes: Oh. Sorry.